# SQL Update Parent ID from Same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Is it possible to update self referencing parent id with Update From query.

Tables I have

Acc

```
AccID    Name  ParentAccID  AccNumber
01       A       Null        A001
02       B       Null        A002   
03       C       Null        A003
04       D       Null        A004
05       E       Null        A005
```

AccRef

```
AccNumber       MasterAcc    Name
A001             A001         A
A002                          B 
A003             A002         C
A004             A005         D 
A005             A009         E
```

the way it should be joined is with AccNumber and then need to updat AccID in ParentAccID based on MasterAcc of that Acc. Only for existing AccNumber and if AccNumber and MasterAcc is not same (sorry if its big confusing)

Result table should look like

Acc

```
AccID    Name  ParentAccID  AccNumber
01       A       Null        A001
02       B       Null        A002   
03       C       02          A003
04       D       05          A004
05       E       Null        A005
```

Thanks

Comment: Why for AccID=05 your ParentAccID is null in your expected result?

Comment: AccId=05 is from AccNumber A005 which has MasterAcc = 'A009' which doesn't exist in Acc table (if you join on AccNumber)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @Acc Table (AccID varchar(10),Name  varchar(200),ParentAccID  varchar(200), AccNumber varchar(200))
Insert into @Acc Values 
('01','A',Null,'A001'),
('02','B',Null,'A002'),   
('03','C',Null,'A003'),
('04','D',Null,'A004'),
('05','E',Null,'A005')

DECLARE @AccRef Table (AccNumber varchar(10),MasterAcc varchar(200),Name  varchar(200))
Insert into @AccRef Values 
('A001','A001','A'),
('A002',Null,'B'), 
('A003','A002','C'),
('A004','A005','D'), 
('A005','A009','E')

Update A set ParentAccID = M.AccID From @Acc A
Inner Join @AccRef R on R.AccNumber = A.AccNumber and R.AccNumber <> R.MasterAcc
Inner Join @Acc M on M.AccNumber = R.MasterAcc
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Finally,

```
Select * from @Acc
```

[image: Output]

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks